# Is it true that $\xi \in \partial G (v)$ implies $\frac{\xi}{F'(\phi (v))} \in \partial \phi (v)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, optimal-transportation, gradient-flows

I am reading the introduction of *Chapter 10* in the book *Gradient Flows* by Ambrosio and his coauthors.

> As we have seen in **Section 1.4**, in the classical theory of subdifferential calculus for proper, lower semicontinuous functionals $\phi: X \rightarrow(-\infty,+\infty]$ defined in a Hilbert space $X$, the *Fréchet Subdifferential* $\partial \phi: X \rightarrow 2^X$ of $\phi$ is a multivalued operator defined as
> $$
> \xi \in \partial \phi(v) \Longleftrightarrow v \in D(\phi), \quad \liminf _{w \rightarrow v} \frac{\phi(w)-\phi(v)-\langle\xi, w-v\rangle}{|w-v|} \geq 0,
> \qquad (*)
> $$
> which we will also write in the equivalent form for $v \in D(\phi)$
> $$
> \xi \in \partial \phi(v) \Longleftrightarrow \phi(w) \geq \phi(v)+\langle\xi, w-v\rangle+o(|w-v|) \quad \text { as } w \rightarrow v
> $$

Above $D(\phi) := \{v \in X : \phi(v)  \neq + \infty\}$ is the proper domain of $\phi$. Now we assume that $\phi$ is non-negative. We consider another function $F: [0, +\infty) \to [0, +\infty)$ with the convention that $F(+\infty) = +\infty$. We assume that $F$ is convex differentiable such that $F'(x)  > 0$ for all $x \in [0, +\infty)$.

Let $G := F \circ \phi$. I would like to ask if the following "chain rule" holds, i.e.,
$$
\xi \in \partial G (v) \implies \frac{\xi}{F'(\phi (v))} \in \partial \phi (v).
$$

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\p}{\partial}\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle #1,#2\rangle}$The answer is yes.

Indeed, suppose the contrary: for some $v\in X$, some $\zeta\in\p G(v)$, some sequence $(w_n)$ in $X$ converging to $v$, some real $\ep>0$, and all $n$ we have
\begin{equation}
    \phi(w_n)\le\phi(v)+\ip\xi{w_n-v}-\ep|w_n-v|, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    \xi:=\frac{\zeta}{F'(\phi(v))}. 
\end{equation}
The condition $F'>0$ implies that $F$ is increasing. So, \eqref{1} and the mean value theorem imply
\begin{equation}
    F(\phi(w_n))\le F(\phi(v)+\ip\xi{w_n-v}-\ep|w_n-v|) \\ 
    =F(\phi(v))+F'(c_n)(\ip\xi{w_n-v}-\ep|w_n-v|)
\end{equation}
for some sequence $(c_n)$ converging to $\phi(v)$.
Also, since $F$ is convex and differentiable, we see that $F'$ is continuous and hence $F'(c_n)\to F'(\phi(v))$. So, without loss of generality, for some real $\de>0$ -- say, for $\de=F'(\phi(v))\ep/2$ -- and all $n$ we have $F(\phi(w_n))\le F(\phi(v))+\ip\zeta{w_n-v}-\de|w_n-v|$, that is,
\begin{equation}
    G(w_n)\le G(v)+\ip\zeta{w_n-v}-\de|w_n-v|,
\end{equation}
which contradicts the condition $\zeta\in\p G(v)$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much for your help.